# Type mismatch: cannot convert from WebElement to WebDriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from WebElement to WebDriver`

Getting this error in my code why?

```
package testcases;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class WebDriver_vs_WebElement {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WebDriver driver;
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("searchLanguage"));
        
        WebDriver block = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"www-wikipedia-org\"]/div[11]/div[3]"));
        List<WebElement> links = block.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println("Total links in particular block: " +links.size());
        for(WebElement link:links)
        {
            System.out.println(link.getText() + "---URL : " +link.getAttribute("href"));
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: What line of code is the offender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WebDriver block = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"www-wikipedia-org\"]/div[11]/div[3]"));
```

A WebDriver is not an WebElement; objects of these types are in different objects hierarchies.

[image]

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.50.1/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html

[image]

https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.50.1/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html

Thus you need a WebElement variable to hold a WebElement object:

```
WebElement block = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"www-wikipedia-org\"]/div[11]/div[3]"));
```